# I would like to notify users if an order is complete after PayPal IPN and order saved to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, paypal, paypal-ipn

As the title states, I would like to notify buyers after they purchase an item on my site through PayPal if the order was a success or if something went wrong. The flow is a buyer goes to an item listing page. Clicks pay and is brought to the new orders page and click Check out with PayPal.

After they are brought to the PayPal checkout and pay for an order, the PayPal IPN notifies the OrdersControoler Orders#Notify action and if it is verified then it saves the order to the database.

The PayPal Adaptive Payments Pay build_pay method create the parameters to be sent to PayPal including the return and cancel URLs. I am not sure how to go about adding a notify or alert to this.

Anyway here is code for the controller.

## OrdersController

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:notify]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  protect_from_forgery :except => [:notify]

  def sales
    @orders = Order.all.where(seller: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def purchases
    @orders = Order.all.where(buyer: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @@order = Order.new(order_params)
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
    @seller = @item.user

    @@order.item_id = @item.id
    @@order.buyer_id = current_user.id
    @@order.seller_id = @seller.id

    # p = Print.find_by(id: params[:id])
    # creator = Creator.find_by(id: p.creator_id)
    price = (@item.price + @item.shipping_price.to_i)
    commission = 0.06

    # Build API call
    @api = PayPal::SDK::AdaptivePayments.new
    @pay = @api.build_pay({
      :actionType => "PAY",
      :cancelUrl => "http://f4bd4637.ngrok.io" + new_item_order_path,
      :returnUrl => root_url,
      :currencyCode => "USD",
      :feesPayer => "PRIMARYRECEIVER",
      :ipnNotificationUrl => "http://f4bd4637.ngrok.io" + paypal_ipn_notify_path,
      :receiverList => {
        :receiver => [
          {
            :amount => price,
            :email => @@order.item.paypal_email,
            :primary => true
          },
          {
            :amount => price * commission,
            :email => "example@gmail.com",
            :primary => false
          }
        ]
      }})

   # Make API call
    @pay_response = @api.pay(@pay)

    # Check if call was valid, if so, redirect to PayPal payment url
    if @pay_response.success?
      @pay_response.payKey
      redirect_to @api.payment_url(@pay_response)
    else
      redirect_to root_path, alert: @pay_response.error[0].message
    end

  end

  def notify
    response = validate_IPN_notification(request.raw_post)
    case response
    when "VERIFIED"
      @@order.save
    when "INVALID"
    else
    end
    render :nothing => true
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_params
      if params[:orders] && params[:orders][:stripe_card_token].present?
        params.require(:orders).permit(:stripe_card_token)
      end
    end

  protected
  def validate_IPN_notification(raw)
    uri = URI.parse('https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate')
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.open_timeout = 60
    http.read_timeout = 60
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    http.use_ssl = true
    response = http.post(uri.request_uri, raw,
                         'Content-Length' => "#{raw.size}",
                         'User-Agent' => "My custom user agent"
                       ).body
  end

end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @unkmas How do I notify the user upon redirect that the payment/order was successful. When I receive a success message from IPN it saves their order, but the PayPal adaptive payments API has a return URL that redirects but I don't know how to show a notice or alert through that.